# Naming Java library how-to?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

can anyone explain how to choose name for Java library, that it be one time repeat?

Comment: Just prefix it with "j". That's about as much thought as most put into naming.

Comment: how to check is it available for use? (not duplicate)

Comment: @user488963 updated my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177762/naming-java-library-how-to/4177784#4177784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Name should explain functionality.
- should be short.
- cool name would be better (for example XStream).

> how to check is it available for use? (not duplicate)

You can

- google it (I think this is the most common way to find existance)

there is not much possibility of duplication after googling it.

Answer (score 1):

Short, memorable, name should be connected with library's purpose. I've always thought [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is a good example of a well named library, or a framework, depending on what it's declared to be. It doesn't have to start with letter "J", although it's become almost a convention.